# Invalid data array response in Advanced Rest Client

Tags: php, mysql, json, rest

I'm attempting to build an "API" in PHP that can take a JSON data array, convert this to PHP data, and then update a MySQL database. POSTing the data straight to the script works fine, as does running it via cURL, but I don't seem to be able to get a response when using Google Chrome's "Advanced Rest Client" app.

I receive a Status: 200 OK message, but the Raw/Parsed response just reads "Invalid data array.".

This is the script in question:

```
<?php
$api = json_decode($_POST['api'], true);

$api['ExhibitorData'] = array_values($api['ExhibitorData']);
$data = $api['ExhibitorData'][0];
$exhibitor_id = $data['exhibitor_id'];

require_once 'config-api.php4'; // database connection

// get some data based on $exhibitor_id

$do_update = mysql_query("UPDATE table SET ... WHERE exhibitor_id = $exhibitor_id");
if (!$do_update)
{
    http_response_code(404);
    die(mysql_error());
}
$do_another_update = mysql_query("UPDATE another_table SET ... WHERE exhibitor_id = $exhibitor_id");
if (!$do_another_update)
{
    http_response_code(404);
    die(mysql_error());
}

$log = mysql_query("INSERT INTO log SET exhibitor_id = $exhibitor_id, ip_address = '" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "', updated_at = NOW()");

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode(array(mysql_insert_id() => 'OK'));

mysql_close();
```

Following online tutorials about creating your own REST API (namely [this one](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2015/10/creating-a-simple-rest-api-in-php/)), I seem to be doing everything correct, but I don't seem to be able to garner a response.

Is there anything else I should be doing?

**EDIT:** This is the structure of the JSON string I am passing to the script:

```
{
    "ExhibitorData": {
        "1": {
            "exhibitor_id": 1,
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are also missing error handling on your last query call. It appears to be wrong, since in an INSERT statement, you don't use SET, but [VALUES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) instead.

Not quite question-related, but what php version do you use? i'm a bit confused by the .php4 extension. Also, you should not use the deprecated mysql_* extension. instead, use the improved [mysqli extension](http://php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: @TanuelMategi Oh, we're on v5.x, but the server is littered with .php4 extensions and mysql_* code from a previous developer about a decade ago. It's just something I have to deal with.

Comment: Ignore where i said you should use `VALUES` instead of `SET`, i looked up the syntax again and apparently `SET` is also valid :S But still do error handling ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work out what the problem was.

When you're POSTing data normally, you access it through the `$_POST` variable. However it seems using cURL, despite saying it POSTs the data, you actually need to access it in a different way.

Changing this line:

```
$api = json_decode($_POST['api'], true);
```

to this:

```
$api = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

then lets the rest of the script run fine.